# Very large loss values when training multiple regression model in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, linear-regression, loss-function

I was trying to build a multiple regression model to predict housing prices using the following features:

```
  [bedrooms  bathrooms  sqft_living  view  grade]
= [0.09375   0.266667     0.149582   0.0    0.6]
```

I have standardized and scaled the features using `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler`.

I used Keras to build the model:

```py
def build_model(X_train):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))
        model.add(Dense(1))

    optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001)

    model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = optimizer)

    return model
```

When I go to train the model, my loss values are insanely high, something like 4 or 40 trillion and it will only go down about a million per epoch making training infeasibly slow. At first I tried increasing the learning rate, but it didn't help much. Then I did some searching and found that others have used a log-MSE loss function so I tried it and my model seemed to work fine. (Started at 140 loss, went down to 0.2 after 400 epochs)

**My question is do I always just use log-MSE when I see very large MSE values for linear/multiple regression problems? Or are there other things i can do to try and fix this issue?**

A guess as to why this issue occurred is the scale between my predictor and response variables were vastly different. `X`'s are between 0-1 while the highest `Y` went up to 8 million. (Am I suppose to scale down my `Y`'s? And then scale back up for predicting?)

Comment: you might have overfitting, you can plot loss functions and check it out nevertheless you can report MSA or MAE or RMSE

Comment: I guess my question is: if i see really large loss values and it is going down too slowly (or just a loss function not working well in general), should i try a different loss function OR tweak other things such as scaling my Y's, learning rate etc. and stick to the same loss function. Or are both options viable and just find what works? (Is there a best practice for this?) I am currently leaning towards trying other loss functions as it seems to be less work to get it working.

Comment: You can try removing values which are not in the Inter-Quartile Range. This helps in removing extreme values which might negatively affect the learning of the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of people believe in scaling everything. If your `y` goes up to 8 million, I'd scale it, yes, and reverse the scaling when you get predictions out, later.

Don't worry too much about specifically what `loss` number you see. Sure, 40 trillion is a bit ridiculously high, indicating changes may need to be made to the network architecture or parameters. The main concern is whether the validation loss is actually decreasing, and the network actually learning therewith. If, as you say, it 'went down to 0.2 after 400 epochs', then it sounds like you're on the right track.

There are many other loss functions besides log-mse, mse, and mae, for regression problems. Have a look at [these](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/5-regression-loss-functions-all-machine-learners-should-know-4fb140e9d4b0). Hope that helps!

Comment: I guess my question is: if i see really large loss values and it is going down too slowly (or just a loss function not working well in general), should i try a different loss function OR tweak other things such as scaling my Y's, learning rate etc. and stick to the same loss function. Or are both options viable and just find what works? (Is there a best practice for this?) I am currently leaning towards trying other loss functions as it seems to be less work to get it working.

Comment: Yeah, if you know the interaction between a loss function and the shape of your data's distribution, then you might be able to make an educated selection, but most of the time I just see loss function as a [grid-search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) parameter; trial and error. Grid searching might help you do (most of) the above at one time! :)